# Why do I get an error when trying to sum values of a column retrieved in a ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

whats wrong with my codes? I think its in the `SQL` but I don't know why. thank you in advance

```
try{
    clsConnect c = new clsConnect();
    Connection conn = c.makeConnection();
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    String display = "SELECT SUM(Amountpaid) from mofficetbl";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(display);
    while(rs.next()){
        totalTF.setText(rs.getString("Amountpaid"));
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: does the table `mofficetbl` have a column `amountpaid`?

Comment: Have you tried running your SQL code directly from MySQL using Workbench (or similar)?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes the table has a column name Amountpaid

Comment: @PM77-1 i tried to run it in mysql console and the sql code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `SUM(amountpaid)` and trying to access the column `amountpaid`, but that column doesn't actually exist in the `ResultSet` Try `rs.getString(1)` or giving the SUM a name in the select as `SELECT SUM(amountpaid) as sum from msofficetbl` then doing `rs.getString("sum");`

Answer (score 3):

when you call this select statement; the returned column is actually called "SUM(amountpaid)" and not amountpaid so either change its alias with

```
"SELECT SUM(Amountpaid) as Amountpaid from mofficetbl"
```

You can also do:

```
rs.getString("Sum(Amountpaid)");
```